# Openssl install failure on MacOS Monterey M1 (arm64) for R 4.2.0 ("Vigorous Calisthenics")

Tags: r, macos, openssl, apple-m1, macos-monterey

I recently upgraded my R version to the [latest release](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) (4.2.0, 2022-04-22). I am receiving this error message when installing [openssl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openssl/index.html) package. I have tried installing from both CRAN and GitHub.

This is the error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘openssl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/openssl’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T//RtmpjQXYpT/file13117452ee57a/openssl_2.0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

And this is the entire log from the session:

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> devtools::install_github("jeroen/openssl")
Downloading GitHub repo jeroen/openssl@HEAD
✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpjQXYpT/remotes1311770b98515/jeroen-openssl-47bf18b/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘openssl’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  running ‘cleanup’
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘openssl_2.0.1.tar.gz’
   
* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** using staged installation
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include
Using PKG_LIBS=-L/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/lib -lssl -lcrypto
** libs
rm -f aes.o base64.o bignum.o cert.o compatibility.o diffie.o envelope.o error.o hash.o info.o keygen.o keys.o onload.o openssh.o password.o pbkdf.o pem.o pkcs12.o pkcs7.o rand.o rsa.o signing.o ssl.o stream.o write.o x25519.o openssl.so bcrypt/libstatbcrypt.a bcrypt/bcrypt_pbkdf.o bcrypt/blowfish.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c aes.c -o aes.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c base64.c -o base64.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c bignum.c -o bignum.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c cert.c -o cert.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c compatibility.c -o compatibility.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c diffie.c -o diffie.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c envelope.c -o envelope.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c error.c -o error.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c hash.c -o hash.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c info.c -o info.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c keygen.c -o keygen.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c keys.c -o keys.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c onload.c -o onload.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c openssh.c -o openssh.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c password.c -o password.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c pbkdf.c -o pbkdf.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c pem.c -o pem.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c pkcs12.c -o pkcs12.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c pkcs7.c -o pkcs7.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c rand.c -o rand.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c rsa.c -o rsa.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c signing.c -o signing.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c ssl.c -o ssl.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c stream.c -o stream.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c write.c -o write.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c x25519.c -o x25519.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c bcrypt/bcrypt_pbkdf.c -o bcrypt/bcrypt_pbkdf.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/include  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c bcrypt/blowfish.c -o bcrypt/blowfish.o
ar rcs bcrypt/libstatbcrypt.a bcrypt/bcrypt_pbkdf.o bcrypt/blowfish.o
clang -arch arm64 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -o openssl.so aes.o base64.o bignum.o cert.o compatibility.o diffie.o envelope.o error.o hash.o info.o keygen.o keys.o onload.o openssh.o password.o pbkdf.o pem.o pkcs12.o pkcs7.o rand.o rsa.o signing.o ssl.o stream.o write.o x25519.o -Lbcrypt -lstatbcrypt -L/private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/lib -lssl -lcrypto -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib'
ld: warning: ignoring file /private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/lib/libcrypto.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /private/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T/RtmpOrSTix/R.INSTALL131a33d271a4b/openssl/.deps/lib/libssl.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘openssl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/openssl’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/5d/z3_6_g1d6d91v4ppjkh4ldnh0000gn/T//RtmpjQXYpT/file13117452ee57a/openssl_2.0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Current session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.3.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13   magrittr_2.0.3    usethis_2.1.5     devtools_2.4.3    pkgload_1.2.4     R6_2.5.1         
 [7] rlang_1.0.2       fastmap_1.1.0     tools_4.2.0       pkgbuild_1.3.1    sessioninfo_1.2.2 cli_3.3.0        
[13] withr_2.5.0       ellipsis_0.3.2    remotes_2.4.2     rprojroot_2.0.3   lifecycle_1.0.1   crayon_1.5.1     
[19] brio_1.1.3        processx_3.5.3    purrr_0.3.4       callr_3.7.0       fs_1.5.2          ps_1.7.0         
[25] curl_4.3.2        testthat_3.1.4    memoise_2.0.1     glue_1.6.2        cachem_1.0.6      compiler_4.2.0   
[31] desc_1.4.1        prettyunits_1.1.1
```

I have openssl@1.1 installed on my machine with homebrew, with the following configurations in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
### openssl:
path+=("/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin")
#path+=("/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin")
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
#export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
# export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig"
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1"
```

Any ideas? I noticed the issue about a week after downloading and installing the new R version when I tried using the `googlesheets4` package.

Comment: More or less same issue. How did you manage to move on with the installation?